# Создать файл по шаблону в intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails

Мну нужно создать gsp файл, но его нет среди стандартных шаблонов

[image: картинка]

Но он есть тут

[image: img]

Как по этому шаблону создать фал?

Comment: Там в комментарии написано, что этот шаблон предлагается при создании новой страницы Groovy Server, насколько я понимаю

Comment: Я чего-то не понимаю. Я создал контроллер, сервис, теперь страницу хочу, но шаблона нет. Как быть?

Comment: Эти шаблоны по идее должны быть доступны в Groovy-проекте при клике правой кнопкой на папке src/ (или какая там для этих страниц сервера) в разделе New

Comment: там ничего нет такого

Comment: какой тип проекта вы используйте?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman grails

Answer (score 1):

В контролере наводите курсор на action и нажимаете **Alt+Enter** в меню выбираете **Create view (GSP page)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]